# Isn't this query ok? MySql one to many with left join and nested query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, left-join, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

After spending a while to find best why to do this job I ended with this query and **I just wonder if it works as I expect ?** Experience has shown MySQL has always a surprise for me that tells me my query is structurally wrong or isn't efficient as expected.

Here is the query :

```
select
      `users`.*,
      `i`.`name` as `identity_name`,
      `i`.`id` as `identity_id`,
      `i`.`is_verified`
    from
      `users`
      left join `identities` as `i` on `i`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
      and `i`.`id` = (
        select
          `i2`.`id`
        from
          `identities` as `i2`
        where
          `i2`.`user_id` = `i`.`user_id`
        order by
          `i2`.`is_verified` desc,
          `i2`.`updated_at` desc
        limit
          1
      )
```

users table :

```
+---+-------------------+
| id| other columns ... |
+---+-------------------+
| 1 | user data ...     |
| 2 | user data ...     |
| 3 | user data ...     |
| 4 | user data ...     |
|...| user data ...     |
+---+-------------------+
```

Identities table :

```
+----+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| id | user_id | is_verified |    name     | updated_at|
+----+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1  |     1   |      0      |  some name  |   2001    |
| 2  |     1   |      1      |  some name  |   2000    |
| 3  |     2   |      0      |  some name  |   2000    |
| 4  |     1   |      0      |  some name  |   2000    |
| 5  |     3   |      1      |  some name  |   2003    |
|... |    ...  |     ...     |  .........  |   ....    |
+----+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Expected output : **for each of user there should be an identity from identities table . identities with is_verified = 1 and then newer updated_at have higher priority**

its obvious that user with id = 1 is the problematic one .

Comment: Your code does not return strictly rows with is_verified = 1. Also why user with id=1 is problematic?

Comment: because id=1 has many different rows in identities table and only one of them should be selected ... my main purpose is to select rows with priority and also I want to have identity for each user (if has any ) even tough user`s identity is not (is_verified = 1 )

Comment: Then I guess your code is fine as it is unless your version of MySql is 8.0+ in which case you could use window functions.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: @newmoon: your code is fine - or if you are running MySQL 8 you can use window functions as demonstrated by forpas (although it will not necessarily be faster). Consider an index on `identities(user_id, is_verified desc, updated_at desc, id)` for performance.

Comment: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Answer (score 1):

If your version of MySql/Mariadb supports window functions you can use  `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select u.*, i.name as identity_name, i.id as identity_id, i.is_verified
from users u 
left join (
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by user_id order by is_verified desc, updated_at desc) rn 
  from identities
) as i on i.user_id = u.id and i.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f63a4b05346a2bf1bbed66046d85c4bc).
Results:

```
> id | other columns | identity_name | identity_id | is_verified
> -: | :------------ | :------------ | ----------: | ----------:
>  1 | user data     | some name     |           2 |           1
>  2 | user data     | some name     |           3 |           0
>  3 | user data     | some name     |           5 |           1
>  4 | user data     | null          |        null |        null
```